# Is there a way to add people to an Outlook calendar without requiring their feedback?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, appointments

We are using Outlook 2007 at work, and a booking administrator would like to schedule appointments and meetings for staff without the staff having to Accept/Decline the bookings.  (Ie, the staff don't want to see all the appointment receipts, and they trust the booking administrator to schedule the appointments so they don't conflict with other appointments.)  Is there a good way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it's pretty easy. :-)

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/prevent-meeting-request-replies-HA010173462.aspx

That links back to a Microsoft article that talks about how to do it. It's one of those things that's hidden away in the ribbon.

Optional vs. required doesn't work the same, as far as I know. You also run the risk of confusing attendees on whether or not they should attend.

If you're looking to help out the person recieving the request, here's your link.
http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/calendar/autoaccept-a-meeting-request-using-rules/

Comment: This is the inverse of what I'm looking for.  The person making the appointments doesn't mind receiving meeting request responses, but the staff DO mind receiving the meeting request emails at all.  They just want the appointments to show up in their calendars without going through the Approve/Deny step.  (Ie, they want the appointments for this particular calendar [note: not all their calendars, just this one] to always be automatically accepted.)

Comment: I see, I misunderstood. It's possible that you can set up a rule within outlook to accept a particular meeting request.

Comment: Updated my answer with the info you actually needed. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You can make them optional attendees. In this case, I think, they may not receive the invite. Try it with a friend first and see what happens.

Comment: It appears that the invite emails still get sent in this case.